# What Superman story was it where Lois Lane had to breathe liquids?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, episode-identification

Way back in the 1960's I regularly got DC comics and in particular Superman.
There was one story where I can only recall a few squares of the comic strip.

For some reason something had been done to Lois Lane and she needed to breathe liquids, however she could function as normal for 4 hours (6 hours? 8 hours?) at a time but then she had to breathe liquids for a few minutes or she would die.

So she's on a plane, twin prop thing, with Clark Kent and several dozen journalists, they're either going to or returning from a major press conference.

Due to turbulence the flight is running very late and they're approaching the 4 hour point but it'll be another half hour until they finish landing, taxi-ing etc. Things are looking grim for Lois because there's no liquids on the plane!

Clark Kent has a moment of inspiration and gets a hat off a fellow journalist, he then goes up and down the passengers and gets his fellow press men to empty their fountain pens in the hat.

He takes this hat brimming with ink and puts it on Lois's lap, she promptly does a face plant into it, she surfaces with a dark blue face (the comic was possibly black and white btw) a couple of minutes later, all relieved to be alive.

The plane lands and she's very happy her hat has a dark veil so she can get to a taxi without attracting attention.

That's all I recall of this story. I do remember, as a geeky little schoolboy, wondering why all those reporters on a plane didn't show the slightest interest in a passenger who breathed liquids.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is [*Superman's Girl Friend, Lois Lane Vol. 1* Issue 60](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman%27s_Girl_Friend,_Lois_Lane_Vol_1_60) (1965), in particular the "The Amazing Hydro-Girl!" story line.

> Lois Lane takes an experimental serum that will let her breathe underwater, but unless she reaches moisture once an hour, she will die...and the Anti-Superman Gang wants to make sure she does.

[image: Clark empties fountain pens ina hat for Lois to dunk her head into]

Comment: Silver age comic are wild!

Comment: Awesome, cheers for this. 55 years since I last saw it!

Comment: ...What kind of passenger plane doesn't have water on board?  Even in the 60's I'd think that'd be standard.  Heck if anything, they'd have more beverages aboard - she could dunk her head in a martini, but, no, they went with ink?  Alrighty then...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman the only liquid aboard apparently was the fuel and the drinking water kept in a tank which the bad guys drain by shooting it.

Comment: This could happen only in a kids' comics book,.

Comment: "Empty all your pens into this hat, as fast as you can!" It is one letter off from the outrage, and even visually, the drawing.. don't tell me it's not on purpose!

Comment: Oh how the internet has ruined us

Comment: @Kaddath: The 1950s tv show had the outrage actually occur -- it was banned in many cities (more than Kirk/Uhura's kiss even) and never shown in reruns -- some say it never happened and those old kinescopes often got destroyed.